# Unable to install anything on a linux on HP t610 Thin Client

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install a Dymo Label Printer on HP t610 Thin Client which has a light read only Linux on it and is connecting to a Citrix environment for users to bring up their virtual desktop.

I have installed the printer driver in the Linux but at the end of the installation it gives me error saying that in order to be able to print I need to install a package and when I try to intall that package from a terminal server I get this error:

```
root@HPc8cbb82fddb9:/writable/usr/lib/dymo-cups-drivers-1.2.0# sudo apt-get install INSTALL
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package hptc-zero-login needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Actually I cannot install anything on this linux. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6):

From the sound of this thread it sounds like with these Thin clients there is "extra" security measures in place. The thread, titled: [T610 Linux based thin client](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Workstations-Thin-Clients/T610-Linux-based-thin-client/td-p/6237829#.Uri0TpBDsoA), describes 2 commands, `fsunlock` and `fslock` which you must run to unlock and then relock the filesystem prior to making any changes.

*excerpt*

> If you're talking about the HP ThinPro OS-
>
> Before you can make changes to the file system, you need to run this command from the terminal - "fsunlock". When you're done, "fslock" locks the file system again. There isn't another file explorer tool included that I'm aware of in ThinPro. Command line and the notepad tool are the only real ways to navigate the file system. If you're looking for help with something, keep in mind it is basically a stripped-down version of Ubuntu, with some extra utilities and GUI provided by HP. The nuts and bolts are the same as an Ubuntu build so I've gotten quite a bit of insight from Ubuntu forums online for problems that I've had.
>
> As for your browser extensions issue, depending on how you're doing this, you can configure connections to allow them to configure their own settings, or to use HP ThinPro settings. If you haven't allowed Firefox to create and use its own settings in the file system, nothing you change inside the browser will stick. I haven't tried installing a browser extension but I'm pretty sure that's where your problem is.

If you're the end user I would caution you that any of these operations I would really look to your system administrators to be doing and/or guiding you in. These types of systems, though look like a standard Linux system are anything but, and a sysadmin should really be doing these types of operations and should be versed in how to do them.